Using divi. Clip-path polygon() on chrome for android makes anything above 2 images disappear
So I'm using a rather long string of clip-path polygon() in the css of images and the 3 I have work fine in all browsers except chrome for android. No matter what I do, the 3rd image I'm trying to use simply doesn't stick around. Now and then I can get it to show up, but after refresh a couple times it disappears for good. Any idea what this might be?
I tried giving it a z-index, I've tried giving it a new string of inputs a few times already. I've tried deleting the other images. Image 1 or 2 cannot be on the same screen together otherwise image 3 disappears. I keep expecting the 3rd image to stay put.

I don't think  we can help without seeing relevant code - any answer at the moment will just be a guess. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and create a runnable snippet which you have tested definitely shows the problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Thanks guys, for some reason I wasn't getting any notifications of replied until now. I fixed it but no idea what the problem truly was... It wasn't the clip-path alone, it was something with the images from the WP image library itself, I made quick rotation edits to the images and now they work just fine.
